# Trying to share access token granted by identity server to a client app using resource owner password grant

Tags: rest, oauth, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have legacy applications in .net framework which have their own separate authentication mechanism going through the database to validate credentials and generating an access token. Now we are trying to use Identity Server to generate an access token , and trying to implement single sign on using this token.

Since all our client applications and api resources are in house, we intend to share this token amongst all our applications.
The web app where user logs in passes the credentials to a rest api. The rest api then talks to IDentityServer4 (using resource owner password grant) to authenticate and get an access token . This token is returned by the rest api to the web app, which then passes it to another web app , which then tries to access another streaming api . The streaming api now needs to validate the token with IS4 , and then allow access to web app2.
The problem we are facing is that :

1) the access token has a limited validity period , after which it will be invalid. The web app2 cannot refresh the access token , as only the initiator of the token ( rest api) is allowed to do that .

2) Even if the rest api takes care of refreshing the access token when its about to expire by using refresh token, a new access token is granted which is not the same as the old token which was shared with other clients.  Is there any way for the web app2 to keep the token alive which was initially granted to the rest api.

I have tried refreshing the token on web app2 , which fails as it is different from the client who owns the token.

I am aware that this is not the best way to use IS4 , and ideally the client apps should be talking to IS4 and authenticating through IS4, and also getting grants to access the api and identity resources , but since we do not want to change all our applications  at once , we are trying to make the api resource talk to IS4 to generate a token.

Is there any way to keep the same access token alive until revoked by the initiator client  ?

Comment: IdentityServer is an implementation of oidc and oauth2. The setup you mention has nothing to do with oidc, e.g. for SSO the user has to login on the IdentityServer website. It seems that your system is not ready for oidc. So IMO this is not the right path to migrate your applications. First make sure you can safely replace Identity from the client/api software without breaking it. Then setup the configuration for the entire system and finally replace Identity with IdentityServer client/api code (startup) for all clients/apis. That'll be more secure and probably a lot easier.

Comment: You are creating a proprietary authentication model here which has nothing to do with OAuth. More likely than not you will end up with more legacy than you have started because you don't have the necessary expertise/resource to come up with robust enough custom auth model. I would suggest to try and retain the core principles of OAuth whilst creating wrappers around your legacy to interface with the new auth model.